# How to highlight search string in AutoComplete results for IOS5?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.5

Google autocomplete would bolden what we search

For example: If we search for *hell* we'll see "**hell** o"

I think I need attributed string, so my code is:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString*) highlightSearchString:(NSString*)substringToHighlight{

    NSMutableAttributedString * mutableAttributedString = [[ NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self];
    NSUInteger count = 0, length = [mutableAttributedString length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);

    count = 0,
    length = [mutableAttributedString length];
    range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:substringToHighlight options:0 range:range];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound) {

            //[mutableAttributedString setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
            NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
            NSDictionary * dict = @{NSFontAttributeName:boldFontName};
            NSRange  rangeHighlight = NSMakeRange(range.location, substringToHighlight.length);
            [mutableAttributedString setAttributes:dict range:rangeHighlight];
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
            count++;
        }
    }
    return mutableAttributedString;
}
```

But it doesn't work because `NSFontAttributeName` is available only in `iOS6`.

After that I need to update the tableViewCell

```
cell.textLabel.text=text;
```

with something that take advantage of the atributed text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the CoreText definition for the font:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]; 
CTFontRef ctFontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL);
NSDictionary * dict = @{(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName : (__bridge id) ctFontRef};
```

For the seconds problem:

The default `UILabel` in the iOS SDK only supports `NSAttributedString` from iOS 6. Thus in 
iOS 5 you will either have to draw the `NSAttributedString` your self using CoreText of get some third part label that does support `NSAttributedString` like: [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel).

Comment: I find out that searchResultsTableView doesn't support NSAttributedString and shows it as NSString in iOS6.

Comment: You could create your own `UITableViewCell` for the `searchResultsTableView` and add the `TTTAttributedLabel` as the label.

Comment: Collection element of type 'CTFontRef' (aka 'const struct __CTFont *') is not an Objective-C object

Comment: Fixed the code, sorry there was a `__bridge` missing. I should work now.