# when adding a new address: when searching the address, there should also be an auto-complete in iphone on searchbar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

We are working on UIMapView set the  geocode for address searching but we are facing the problem is  when adding a new address: when searching the address, there should also be an auto-complete. How is it possible on search Bar?  (As like we are searching the city list on net If we are search Pune then show all P related city name.)
Please solve anybody?

Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077404/autocomplete-search-example-for-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601936/how-to-highlight-search-string-in-autocomplete-results-for-ios5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281798/how-to-search-mkmapview-with-uisearchbar